# Issue with Images in Jekyll on GitHub

Tags: image, github, hyperlink, path, jekyll

I'm having an odd problem with Images when I upload a web site on gh-pages. I used Jekyll to make a static, one page, web site, and for some reason, half of the images are NOT showing. The rest is just fine.

This is the repo I'm having a problem with: https://github.com/Vukasin90/test

What I don't understand is how some images are working just fine, and some are not. Even though they are in the same folder and same path. Pay close attention to "courses" logos. Only one logo (treehouse) is not showing...

btw... When I run it locally, everything works just fine, even though CMD displays ERRORS with finding some folders and images.

Comment: Please point out which images exactly are not showing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community. For starters, it is a good practice to include a [mcve] to your question for faster troubleshooting

Comment: Right now, images from "work" section, except the last one (proj-8, thumb.jpg), and profile picture is not showing (about section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typographical error.

```
/Assets/img/online-kursevi/Treehouse-Logo-small.png
```

should be

```
/Assets/img/online-kursevi/Treehouse-logo-small.png
```

to satisfy

```
courses:
- {avatar: 'Treehouse-logo-small.png', name: 'Treehouse'...
```

in `/_data/settings.yml`.

Comment: Omg, thank you. Although, I don't get it, how come it works just fine on local host? That's why I didn't even noticed the problem.
I just started using Jekyll, so forgive me :D

Comment: Add gem `github-pages` to your Gemfile to ensure that building the site locally gives the same result as how GitHub will build it.

Comment: Is it the same problem with "work" section and profile image? Cause, I don't see problems with links, like with the Treehouse. 
Sorry to bother you, but this drove me crazy for couple of days...

Comment: No, it's fine really, I'm happy to help! Also, I see what the problem is. Jekyll doesn't recognise `.JPG`. It's `.jpg`.

Comment: I changed that from .jpg, because image extension is .JPG. 
Do I need to change image exten.?

Comment: I changed it back to ".jpg", but there's no images still, except for the last one... Should I really change the images with the proper extension (.jpg) ?

Comment: You have to change the extensions of the images as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it tomorrow (it's late here where I am ) I'll ket you know if it worked. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hey, it worked perfectly...thank you so much! 
I'm now left with just one problem. Work section won't load when clicked ( https://github.com/Vukasin90/test/blob/gh-pages/_includes/work.html )
I tried with {{ sit.baseurl }}, with "/", with "../" withouth "/" nothing seems to work. I can feel that it's something wrong with the link :D But idk what. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that, I think it would be better to ask another question. Sorry.